# Which phrase is correct "stiffener set" or "stiffeners set"?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Which phrase is correct to define a set of stiffeners: *"stiffener set"* or *"stiffener**s** set"*?

Comment: What did you find out before asking the question?  Why do you have a doubt?  What is wrong with the phrase "a set of stiffeners"  (this is actually the best option in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nouns used attributively are normally singular, so "stiffener set".  However this does not sound good, since there is no idiomatic use of this phrase.  You should use "a set of stiffeners" in most cases.

Comment: I'm a programmer and we use variable names like "AccountTotalBalance" etc. That's why I'm asking. I was guessing which one is correct "StiffenerSet" or "StiffenersSet".

Comment: That is not English. That is computer code, and the rules of computer code are not the rules of English.  In English you should write "a set of stiffeners"  In computer code you should follow the guidance of the formatting guide.  English rules don't apply.

Comment: If it's in computer code, you should try and be consistent, and see how other variables/classes/etc are named.

Comment: And it's not "Account**s**TotalBalance."